# Find the convergence interval of the power series and investigate the convergence at the ends of the convergence interval

Tags: power-series

I need to find the convergence interval of the power series and investigate the convergence at the ends of the convergence interval for $$\sum_{1}^{\infty}{\frac{(x^n)^n}{n^n}}$$
I tried to apply the Cauchy convergence test:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\sqrt[n]{\frac{(x^n)^n}{n^n})}} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{x^n}{n}}$$
and I don't know what to do with this next.

The answer for this example is: $-1 \leq x \leq 1$.

I would be very grateful if you could point me to a further solution

Comment: For $|x|>1$ the general term of the series tends to $\infty$.